# ROI Pooling layer for character recognition

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe, pycaffe

Trying to understand [this paper](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ECCV_2018/papers/Zhenbo_Xu_Towards_End-to-End_License_ECCV_2018_paper.pdf) for LP recognition.

[image]

Three ROI Pooling layers are used to have features for 7 classifiers.

First one is for Province, second one is for alphabets and the rest are for five alphanumeric characters.
The plate sample is Chinese LP.

[image]

I am confused how these seven classifiers know which respective part of the plate to look at for recognition.

Because all seven classifiers are fed with same concatenated three ROIPooling features as follows.

```
roi1 = roi_pooling_ims(_x1, boxNew.mm(p1), size=(16, 8))
roi2 = roi_pooling_ims(_x3, boxNew.mm(p2), size=(16, 8))
roi3 = roi_pooling_ims(_x5, boxNew.mm(p3), size=(16, 8))
rois = torch.cat((roi1, roi2, roi3), 1)
_rois = rois.view(rois.size(0), -1)

y0 = self.classifier1(_rois)
y1 = self.classifier2(_rois)
y2 = self.classifier3(_rois)
y3 = self.classifier4(_rois)
y4 = self.classifier5(_rois)
y5 = self.classifier6(_rois)
y6 = self.classifier7(_rois)
```

Comment: Haven´t looked at paper or code but I would guess that the loss function will be the one to "force" the model to look at province at y0 and such. As long as loss function penalizes y0 if it didn´t give A, it should learn by itself where to look

Comment: @juvian that means we need to be careful in training not to train repeated digits or alphabets.

Comment: Well, if first training samples had all same character it wouldnt be good yeah, but I doubt you need to take care of not using them. After all, when you will try to recognize a real plate, it can have repeated.